# StringBuilder fails to append a carriage return?

Tags: java

I am trying to append a carriage return to a String Builder like this :-

```
line2 = new StringBuilder(line).append("\r\n").toString();
```

Next, I am writing this to a file using Print Writer. Like this :-

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(FileWriter fw);
pw.println(line2);
```

But in my output file, I am unable to feel the change of carriage return.
I still see the same number of characters present as before.

Please help me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need a `carriage return` if you are using `PrinterWriter's` method `println`

Comment: @avinash may be because you can't see newline character .if you want to test append another word after that

Answer (score 0):

you will see this in PrintWeiter :

```
public void println(String x) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        print(x);
        println();
    }
}
```

it's  always a println();  so you can't find something changed